# iOS - Saving multiple images to Documents folder

Tags: ios, camera, nsdocumentdirectory

I have this code this code to save an image to the Documents folder.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
    UIImage *image = imageView.image; // imageView is my image from camera
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

I am looking for a way to be able to save multiple images as this one keeps over writing the savedImage.png name.

I do not mind looking for it on google or whatever, but I need to know what it is called, since looking with the wrong keywords really delays the world:-)

Cheers

Comment: Do you want each image to be saved to a different file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the file name that you are appending to the image documentsDirectory path on line three.  Each time you'll need to use a different name that isn't already used.  NSFileManager has methods to see if a file exists so you can construct a file name and then test if it exists in that location and if so, increment your duplicate count and try the next one.

if `num` is an integer you define somewhere and keep around so you know the last one you thought you used (and that you've initialized to 1 somewhere).

```
// your code to get the directory here, as above

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager ...]

do {
   savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: 
        [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@-%d.png", @"savedImage", num]];
   num += 1; // for next time

  if ( ![fm fileExistsAtPath: savedImagePath] )
  {
      // save your image here using savedImagePath
      exit;
  }
} while ( //some kind of test for maximum tries/time or whatever )
```

you'll have to look up the syntax to get an NSFileManager instance and the exact file exists method signature, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Not taking th easy way out, but i am not sure how to sort out the while part of the code you gave me. First time I have encountered this sorry:-)

Comment: Think about this:  in a file system if you put a second file in the same location with the same name it will replace the existing file, right?  If you want to save it in the same location you have to give it another name.  In the Finder the finder will do this automatically by appending a number or "copy" to the file name (when you duplicate it).  The code above is just trying to show you this and suggest that you add a number to the end.  Read the documentation for the parts of the above you don't understand. e.g., `stringWithFormat:` or of `NSFileManager` etc.

Comment: you have to learn to read the documentation to understand what existing classes do and how they work.  Rishi's answer above about appending the date is also an option and will maybe be easier since you don't have to test if it already exists (if you include milliseconds).

Comment: If we are not understanding your question then maybe try clarifying it some.

Comment: You are understanding the question and I have implemented your solution. At the while part, I have just entered (nil) for now, until I sort this out.

Comment: that's why it won't work because it'll quit after one iteration so after the first time it'll never save again.  Put `while (true)` for now instead and it'll work.

Comment: is there any possibility of crashing application, while storing more than 1000 images in NSDocumentDirectory?

Answer (score 5):

If you save file with current dateTime you don't need to worry about same name override problem

```
-(NSString*)getCurrentDateTimeAsNSString
{
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [format setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *retStr = [format stringFromDate:now];
    [format release];

    return retStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a new file each time to do that.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOURiMAGEfILE.IMAGEeXTENSION"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
    {
        path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"YOURiMAGEfILE.IMAGEeXTENSION] ];
    }
```

and then you can perform your above operations on the created file.

Comment: Sorry I could not get this solution to work I needed to. Maybe I am misunderstanding it:-)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it help You Working For me!!

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        let i = Int(arc4random())

        let str = String(i).appending(".png")

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent(str)

        print(paths)

        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    }
    else{
        print("error")

    }
```

Comment: While answers are always welcome, please include a brief explanation of *how* the above solves the problem.