# How to avoid overwriting files on iPhone Documents folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

I need to write files containing `NSArrays` into the Documents folder of my iPhone application. Next time I need to create a new file, not overwriting the previous one.

I tried like this, but it only writes `doc0` and `doc1`.

`allDocs` in an `NSArray` declared elsewhere.

What's wrong? Thank you!

```
 NSString *myDoc;
 NSString *temp;

  for (int i = 0; i < [allDocs count]; ++i){
    NSFileManager* fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    myDoc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doc%d.dat", i];
    NSString* currentFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myDoc];
    BOOL fileExists = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:currentFile];
    if (fileExists == NO){
        temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doc%d.dat", i];
        break;
    } else {
        temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doc%d.dat",i++];
        break;
    }
}

NSString *myArray = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myDoc];

NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: myArray];

if(myMutableArray == nil)

{

    myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

    myMutableArray = anotherArray; 
} 

[myMutableArray writeToFile:myArray atomically:YES];
```

Comment: What's the value of `[allDocs count]` before you enter the `for` loop?

Comment: It varies, like from 1 to 20 or more. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Saving FileName with currentDateTime with seconds could save you some trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10671095/1378447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You break out of the for loop on the first iteration each time whether the file is found or not.  You should be looping with incremented values for `i` until `fileExists` is false.

```
- (BOOL) workFileExists:(NSString *)name {
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *filename = [name stringByAppendingString:@".swrk"];

    return [fm fileExistsAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
}

- (NSString *)uniqueUntitledName {
    NSString *untitled = @"Untitled";
    NSString *name = untitled;
    int i = 1;
    while ([self workFileExists:name]) {
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", untitled, i];
        i++;
    }
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Should I use continue, instead?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some code I use in a project.  It has a slightly different style of naming but should work as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the code because I've tried inside the else statement this, but it starts from the higher number and keeps decreasing until it reaches zero  while (fileExists == NO) {
                temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"doc%d.dat",i++];
            }

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImage *imageForShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.jpg"];
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Folder"];
// New Folder is your folder name
NSError *error = nil;

 //in this method you are checking the path is exist or not for Folder Name
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

//now checking the image name already exist or not

NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.jpg"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
{
  NSLog(@"Path is available.");
  NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageForShare, 1.0);
  [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Path doesn't exist, same name of image is already exist.");
}
```

Thank You!!